# Calculate percentage of group using GROUP BY

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing a GROUP BY and COUNT(*) on a dataset, and I would like to calculate the percentage of each group over the total.

For example, in this query, I would like to know how much the count(*) for each state represents over the total ( select count(*) from publicdata:samples.natality ):

```
SELECT state, count(*)
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
GROUP by state
```

There are several ways to do it in SQL, but I haven't found a way to do it in Bigquery, does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: Check ratio_to_report, one of the recently announced window functions (example in an answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check ratio_to_report, one of the recently announced window functions:

```
SELECT state, ratio * 100 AS percent FROM (
 SELECT state, count(*) AS total, RATIO_TO_REPORT(total) OVER() AS ratio
 FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
 GROUP by state
)

state   percent
AL      1.4201828131159113   
AK      0.23521048665998198  
AZ      1.3332896746620975   
AR      0.7709591206172346   
CA      10.008298605982642
```

Comment: Just saw the post from yesterday with the new features, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to use  ROUND with the RATIO_TO_REPORT? Or use *100 for percentage calculation? I'm getting an error Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 1, column 37. Was expecting: ")"

Comment: This is legacy function and is deprecated now

Comment: Not "deprecated", but #standardSQL is preferred for sure (and the best way to move forward). See evan_b answer below.

Answer (score 20):

Modifying Felipe's answer for the standard SQL BigQuery dialect instead of the Legacy SQL dialect looks like this:

```
select state, 100*(state_count / total) as pct
from (
  SELECT state, count(*) AS state_count, sum(count(*)) OVER() AS total
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality` 
  GROUP by state
) s
```

Documentation of the standard SQL BigQuery aggregate analytic functions (aka 'window functions') is here: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

Answer (score 10):

You can use a window function to get the percentage of total by group, without the need for a subquery (improving on evan_b's solution):

```
SELECT 
   state
   ,count(*) / (sum(count(*)) OVER()) as pct
FROM  
   `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality` 
GROUP BY 
   state
```

Comment: Thank you for simple solution!

Answer (score 5):

You can do a self join against the total, using a dummy value as a key. For example:

```
SELECT
  t1.state AS state,
  t1.cnt AS cnt,
  100 * t1.cnt / t2.total as percent
FROM (
  SELECT
    state,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    1 AS key
  FROM
    [publicdata:samples.natality]
  WHERE state is not null
  GROUP BY
    state) AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    1 AS key
  FROM
    [publicdata:samples.natality]) AS t2
ON t1.key = t2.key
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Johnny V's solution, it returns frequencies for me. For calculating actual percentages I found that adding a simple `*100` works:

```
SELECT
  sex
  ,COUNT(*) / (SUM(COUNT(*))OVER()) * 100 AS percentage
FROM `powerful-hall-355408.comic_characters_wikia.dc_comics` 
GROUP BY sex
```